# Create result tree fragment variable

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using an xsl stylesheet to output an xsl:fo document with an SVG chart embedded.

I am having trouble taking an array from the input, and splitting it into several smaller arrays, stored in variables so that the SVG template can be applied to the different arrays to generate 3 different charts. The input looks like this (please note the custom ns):

```
<root xmlns="http://xml.mynamespace.com">
    <data>
        <list>
            <item>
                <id>1</id>
                <title>Foo</title>
                <score>10</score>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>2</id>
                <title>Bar</title>
                <score>6</score>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>3</id>
                <title>Baz</title>
                <score>16</score>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>4</id>
                <title>Fizz</title>
                <score>14</score>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>5</id>
                <title>Buzz</title>
                <score>7</score>
            </item>
        </list>
    </data>
</root>
```

These value can be split into 3 distinct groups. I am trying to split the array `list` into 3 separate variables to that a template can be applied to turn them into an SVG chart. The SVG transform is known to work for the array as above, so I think the problem is the way I am trying to create the variables. I have tried a few different ways, but I have had the most success (if you can call it that) using xsl:copy-of as so (again, please be aware of the ns):

```
<xslt:stylesheet xmlns:m="http://xml.mynamespace.com" version="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="group1">
        <xsl:element name="m:list">
            <xsl:copy-of select="/m:root/m:data/m:list/m:item[id &lt;= 3]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:variable>
</xslt:stylesheet>
```

and then later the variable is used like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($group1)/m:list" />
```

The reason I am putting them in variables is because the template that creates the SVG expects input in the format of `<list>` with one or more child `item` elements. The SVG transform template is as so:

```
<xsl:template match="m:list">
    <xsl:variable name="canvasHeight" select="28 * count(m:item)"/>
    <svg height="{$canvasHeight}">
        <xsl:for-each select="m:item">
            <!-- Draw bar here -->
        </xsl:for-each>
    </svg>
</xsl:template>
```

The output when I try to transform the variable to SVG as above indicates that the `list` element is created correctly (because the template matches and the SVG element is output) but the `item` elements aren't copied because the for-each doesn't seem to have executed and the outputted height is 0.

Am I incorrectly creating the variable `group1`? Or is there an easier way to do this that doesn't require splitting the initial list into separate variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well with `/m:root/m:data/m:list/m:item[Id &lt;= 3]` you simply have the wrong case (`Id` versus `id`) and the wrong namespace (none versus `m:id`) in the predicate.

Comment: The Id bit was a typo, however the namespace was the root cause, thank you. That's been driving me mad all morning